# Changing dynamic text with text from text file with actionscript 3

Tags: flash, text, actionscript, external, string-formatting

I'm trying to make a flash where the text dynamically updates from a text file every time the .swf file is started.

I'm not the brightest when it comes to this, but I will try and explain what I want to make.

I want to have a .txt file in a certain format. Similar to this

example:

```
    Team1: Time
    Player1: Dusk
    Player2: Dawn
    Player3: Noon
    Team2: Food
    Player1: Pizza
    Player2: Cheese
    Player3: Bread
```

And then output the text after each element and output them to a dynamic text object with the same name.

I would have an empty text object named Team1: Where after this script is run it would say "Time" instead of blank.

I've tried a few different ways of reading the file, but it's when it comes to the splitting and sending it to the dynamic text objects I have trouble.

The end result with proper adjusting from flash would look something like this

```
    Time        vs        Food
    Dusk                  Pizza
    Dawn                  Cheese
    Noon                  Bread
```

This is the current code of what I have as of right now

```
    var TextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    TextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
    function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
        var PlayerArray:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
    }
   TextLoader.load(new URLRequest("roster1.txt"));
```

So the question is really, how do I split this properly with the formatting I use and then set the dynamic text to the text followed by the tag (team1:, player1:, etc)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty attempt at splitting the data:

It assumes the prefix and value will be separated by ": " and that "Team" is used to determine the start of a team.

It loops through the array of strings and splits each string along  ": ", then checks to see if the prefix contains the string "Team" to determine if it is the start of a new team or is currently a player of the current team.

```
//assumes this is the starting state of the data
var playerArray:Array = new Array();
playerArray.push("Team1: Time",
"Player1: Dusk",
"Player2: Dawn",
"Player3: Noon",
"Team2: Food",
"Player1: Pizza",
"Player2: Cheese",
"Player3: Bread");

var teams:Array = new Array();
var currentTeam:Array = new Array();;
var prefix:String;
var value:String;
for(var counter:int = 0; counter < playerArray.length; counter++){
    prefix = playerArray[counter].substring(0, playerArray[counter].indexOf(": "));
    value =  playerArray[counter].substring(playerArray[counter].indexOf(": ") + ": ".length);

    // found a team prefix, this is the start of a new team
    if(prefix.indexOf("Team") != -1){
        teams.push(currentTeam);
        currentTeam = new Array();
        currentTeam.push(value); // add the name of the currentTeam to the array
    } else {
        // else this should be a player, add it to the currentTeam array
        currentTeam.push(value);
    }
}
// add the last team
teams.push(currentTeam);
// remove the first empty team array just due to the way the loop works
teams.shift();

trace(teams.length); // traces 2
trace(teams[0]); // traces the team members of first team
trace(teams[1]); // traces the team members of next team
```

The result is an array of team arrays, where each team array's index 0 is the team name followed by the players.

From here you should just be able to create the textfields (or use existing ones) and set the text from the arrays.

Perhaps others can come up with a more efficient method? I also tried to see if it was possible by combining it into a long string and splitting along "Team", then "Player", then ": ", to try and separate it out, but it got more messy and possibly error prone if a player's name contained "Team" or "Player" in it.